# How to Add multiple instance of meta box to custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am able to make custom post type and custom meta box but my situation is that i want to attach multiple instance of custom meta box to custom post type.

my custom post type is show which have custom fields like start date,link,venue lets call it showinfo

now for every show i can have multiple showinfo

so how to achieve that

in attached image see show events time box in right middle side of picture that better explain what i am asking 
[image: sample image]

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

If the maximum number of instances of showinfo is small, then you could just put them all in one meta box.

If the number is large or unlimited, the you would be better off creating another custom post type like "showinfo". You could create this the same way you created your existing post type.

Then define a custom metabox (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) to each of the showinfo posts with the same information as you have in the right-hand column example in your question.

In addition, put a SELECT drop-down in the Meta Box listing all of the existing shows, and require that the person creating the showinfo pick one.

All of the information from the Meta Box gets stored as post_meta for the showinfo post. You can have as many show times (showinfo posts) as you want for a show.

When you want to display the show information for show, just use a custom query  to get all of the showinfo. For example:

```
$args=array(
  'meta_key'=>'show',
  'meta_value'=> 'some show identifier',
  'post_type' => 'showinfo',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: can you pl. help me regarding code wise how we do it?

Comment: Which approach are you wanting to implement?

Comment: 2nd one i think is most suitable for me